# How to make jQuery methods work in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I know I can use the jQuery `.each()` function (and it works fine), but the performance is too sluggish. So I want to use a for loop and have the jQuery methods available inside it. 
For example:

```js
var anArray = $('#somediv').children(); // it has a lot of children
for(i=0;i<anArray.length;i++) { // or for(i=anArray.length;i--;)
  anArray[i].addClass('sample_class'); // and a bunch of other stuff
};
```

Right now the browser throws this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'addClass'`

Think it had something to do with the jQuery wrapper `$()`
I know I read the solution somewhere a while ago, but I'm just unable to retrace it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly , wrap it , because they are DOM elements and actually has no `addClass` method  :

```
$(anArray[i]).addClass('sample_class');
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/children/

Comment: Gosh, should have tried it on every action in the for loop; thanks for quick reply. +1  Performance-wise, is it better to use the jQuery wrapper, or use the native JS .className? I suppose the native method?

Comment: @Tyblitz you know , you'll feel some difference  if you have hundreds of hundreds dom nodes. but in any case seems like `$` wrapping is a little bit expensive operation..

Comment: Seems like someone took the time to do the test: http://jsperf.com/addclass-v-classname

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the equivalent `addClass` for Javascript

```
anArray[i].className = "sample_class";
```

Comment: oh really? Thanks for this, thought Js only allowed for id manipulation; +1